# Who makes the best server racks/cabinets?

Tags: hardware, rack

Who makes the best [19 inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19-inch_rack) server racks/cabinets?

I'm considering the following brands in a four post, square hole configuration:

- [APC](http://www.apc.com/products/category.cfm?id=10)
- [Wright Line](http://www.wrightline.com/products/viewproducts.html?category=22)
- [Rittal](http://www.rittal.com/products/it-solutions/index.html)
- [Chatsworth](http://www.chatsworth.com/Products/Cabinet-and-Enclosure-Systems/Server-Cabinet/)
- [Great Lakes](http://www.werackyourworld.com/products/)
- [Middle Atlantic](http://www.middleatlantic.com/enclosure/main.htm)
- [HP](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/racks/10000series/index.html)

My requirements, in rough order of priority include:

- Configurability (depth in particular)
- Accessories (Zero U PDU, cable management, 1U KVM, drawers, etc)
- Design features (Numbered U's)
- Fit and finish
- Stability
- Ability to connect multiple racks/cabinets together

The final build will be a total of 5 racks for a private cage.  Sides/doors/tops/bottoms are nice to have but optional.  We have primarily Dell 1U servers (R610, R210, R710) some SuperMicro 2U, several off brand disk storage enclosures, plus TBD network switches, routers, firewalls.

Answer (score 3):

I love my HP racks, because they actually say "Compaq" on the front, and they're a lovely "Mercedes Brown" colour that complements all of my Compaq and HP servers.

Oh, and there's the small matter that all the Compaq/HP rails fit perfectly, and the non-HP stuff fits fine, too.  I've never heard of Great Lakes or Middle Atlantic, but I've seen APC and Wright-Line racks that are just as good as my HPs.

[HP Rack 10000 G2 Series QuickSpecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12402_na/12402_na.html), which give you some idea of the available rack options.